# hierarchical select not working in multistep form

Tags: forms, taxonomy-terms

I have created multistep form with help of

[link](http://www.grasmash.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7)
 and created hierarchial select in step 1.It is working for step 1
but when i click next button and goes to step2, and return step1 it is not working.

Please Help.

Comment: How are you passing the select to second step?

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping this will add more info to the above reporting, even though we have different websites, to hopefully enable a fix.

I have a 2 level hierarchical select taxonomy.  Refer to it in my people pages.  Created as Term Reference - Hierarchical Select. When registering a user go to select this term, which is supposed to save term lineage, forces user to select term from deepest level.

- Selecting from pulldown menu and clicking add, it appears that the item is being selected correctly and shows up below the pulldown menu, with the option to remove the selection.  I then save, it says everything was saved correctly.  I scroll down to my selection, and it says nothing has been selected.

- If I go to a view based off of this information, it indeed finds no data.
- I do get data if I change the field from hierarchical select to List Select or check boxes and have the view be rendered taxonomy term.  If I have to use List Select I will have to change the terms to include the first level since it doesn't show or save this way. This list is going to expand as new courses get added.  We can't do check boxes perpetually.  It will get crazy long.

I did find this **error message log**, but I don't know after which change this appeared.
Notice: Undefined index: value in views_handler_filter_term_node_tid->value_validate() (line 219 of /var/www/vehicledev_ccom_nh/sites/all/modules/views/modules/taxonomy/views_handler_filter_term_node_tid.inc).

Severity
notice